# How can I check if an object is already in a three.js scene and then replace it?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How can I check if an object is already in a three.js scene and then replace it? I suspect this is more of a scope issue than a three.js one, but…

I have a form that is initiated on a click that asks users to, basically, customize some options related to the model. When it is submitted, I want the app to check if an object already exists in the same location (I do this by assigning a name to the object when it is created). If something is already there, replace it with the new selection.

I've got the checking mechanism working, but am still having trouble with replacing:

```
var places = [];
$('#submit').off().on("click", function(){
        //create a variable that stores info from the selections
        place = motifClass.toString() + placeValue.toString();
        motifChecker(place);

        if (places.indexOf(place) === -1 ){
         places.push(place);
        };

        ….

        var loader = new STLLoader().load(‘/assets/object.stl’, function( geometry ){
        …

        mesh.name = place;
        place = "";
        scene.add(mesh);
    };

});

  function motifChecker(){
      var existing = scene.getObjectByName(place);
      if ( places.includes(place) ){
         scene.remove(existing);
      }
  };
```

which removes the object, but doesn’t seem to replace it. My browser console tells me the new stl file is loaded, but it isn't appearing in the screen.

Comment: is this your actual code because 1 ) you are missing passing place variable to motifChecker function

Comment: In line 4 I do that...unless I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: hi sorry for being late...is variable place global ? because you are not passing it to the function motifChecker()

Answer (score 0):

you should dispose the existing after remove it

```
existing.geometry.dispose();
existing.geometry = undefined;
existing.material.dispose();
existing.material = undefined;
scene.remove(existing)
```

Comment: That returns "existing.dispose()" is not a function on the last line.

Comment: Sorry to my mistake. The last line should be `scene.remove(existing);`